# new event log is linked to application event log

Tags: powershell, logging

I'm using Powershell v3.0

I'm trying to create a new Event Log.
When I create the Event Log it appears to be a copy of the Application log.

- The new log has all of the application logs messages in it,
- new events that are written to the application log shows up in both,
- new events written to the new log show up in both,
- if I delete the new event log, the application log contents are
  deleted (0 records).

Here is the code that creates the new event log:

```
#Add Event Log if not already added
$CheckEL = @(Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.Log -eq $EventLogName})

if($CheckEL.Count -eq 0){
    if ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($EventLogSource)){
        [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::DeleteEventSource($EventLogSource)
    }
    New-EventLog -LogName $EventLogName -Source $EventLogSource -ErrorAction Stop
    Limit-EventLog -LogName $EventLogName -OverflowAction OverWriteAsNeeded -MaximumSize 64KB
}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems part of the problem was a scope issue. When I rebooted one of the servers that was having the problem I was able to Remove-EventLog "OpsBrain" and then New-EventLog -LogName "OpsBrain" worked as expected. I'm still not sure what I did in the first place to cause it to link to the application log.

Answer (score 0):

If I do about the same:

```
$EventLogName = "OpsBrain"; 
$EventLogSource="OpsBrainService" 

#Test if Event Log not already exists
$CheckEL = @(Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.Log -eq $EventLogName})

if($CheckEL.Count -eq 0){
    #Event Log does not yet exists, create it:        
    New-EventLog -LogName $EventLogName -Source $EventLogSource
}
```

And I write something to the eventlog (otherwise you cannot retrieve the contents of the log file):

```
Write-EventLog OpsBrain -Source $EventLogSource -EventId 1 -Message "Test"
```

Then I only retrieve that one object:

```
Get-EventLog OpsBrain

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
       1 mrt 09 12:26  Information OpsBrainService                 1 Test
```

Comment: $EventLogName = "OpsBrain"; $EventLogSource="OpsBrainService"

Comment: I've expanded my answer. Can you check above?

Comment: After cleaning up previous attempts I had 0 events in my Application log. I added one event. Then I ran the code you posted. I now have an OpsBrain event log, with one event. That is, it again cloned the Application log. But at least I know that it works as designed "somewhere." It must be something in my environment.

Comment: Is it possible to post more code? Maybe there is something else wrong?